# I do not understand this slicing or reshape in numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

full code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W6k_nq890Fj5StsUtK4Hs1vorUgu0moA

Some how it reshapes or slices from (3621, 30, 1)
to (1150,). I do not understand.
Thank You for your help!

```py
print(len(series[..., np.newaxis]))
print((tf.expand_dims(series[..., np.newaxis], axis=-1).shape))
rnn_forecast = model_forecast(model, series[..., np.newaxis], window_size)
print("before reshape: "+str(rnn_forecast.shape))
rnn_forecast = rnn_forecast[split_time - window_size:-1, -1, 0]
print("After reshape: "+str(rnn_forecast.shape))

output:
3650
(3650, 1, 1)
before reshape: (3591, 60, 1)
After reshape: (1150,)
```

Comment: The `np.newaxis` and `tf.exapnd_dims` each add a dimension, resulting in the (3650,1,1) shape.  `rnn_forecast[split_time - window_size:-1, -1, 0]` selects items from the (3591, 69, 1)` array - a slice on the first dimension, scalar indices on the other 2.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not perform a reshape.
The **getitem** call between the two print statements selects a slice for each of the three axes
For axis 0 the slice is split_time-window_size -1:-1  so ends at index 3648
For axis 1 the slice is single index -1, equivalent to index 29 for this example
For axis 2 the slice is single index 0

Result is an array with just a single axis.

In short, reshape plays no role in this example